# Pandas ValueError: Function does not reduce

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have been trying to use pandas groupby to analyze data, then I encountered an issue after update pandas from version 0.15.0 to 0.18.1 that did not exist before.

I want to calculate the number of consercutive periods where the value of 'equality' is 1 (it can only take values of 0 or 1). I defined the followin lambda function, and used groupby command as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    E = lambda x: np.sum(x.diff()==1) + x.head(1)

    grouped = df.groupby(['run_'])
    agg_data = grouped[['equality','avg_payoff']].mean()
    agg_data['E'] = grouped.equality.agg(E) # number of "equality" epochs
```

but received the error message for the last line of code:

```
    ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

It is weird that this code ran perfectly before update. This is not the first time that I encounter an issue after update of scientific computing packages, which makes me a bit frustrated.Could anyone help solve the issue? Or I have to roll back to the old versions...

Comment: Would you mind showing some of the data you are working with so we can replicate?

Answer (score 1):

x.head(1) returns series (with one row but series).
You can make a silly workaround like this

```
E = lambda x: np.sum(x.diff()==1) + np.sum(x.head(1))
```

or a little bit smarter

```
E = lambda x: np.sum(x.diff()==1) + x.iloc[0]
```

Comment: or x.head().values which saves the call to external methods, and is probably optimised to that operation.

Comment: @Chris Is x.head().values more effective than x.iloc[0]?

Comment: Well, from the source of NDFrame, the parent class for pandas, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py, .values returns the internal array used by pandas, (df._data). The difference is obviously not consequential in this case, but iloc will have more overhead in general as .values is just copying data you have already operated on.

Comment: @Chris I checked your solution - x.head().values has type numpy.ndarray, not scalar. So there is "Exception: Must produce aggregated value" again.